# Download ISO file from redhat site

Tags: iso-image, redhat-enterprise-linux, wget, curl

we want to download from redhat site rhel 7.6 ISO file in order to install docker ( https://nathancatania.com/posts/installing-docker-on-red-hat-with-no-internet-access )

redhat site - https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/69/ver=/rhel---7/7.6/x86_64/product-software

example from redhat site

[image]

but instead to download it from the web page , we want to download it directly  to rhel machine as

```
curl -o  /var/ISO/rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso  ....
```

but how to know the full path of the http ?

.
.

we tried the following but its not download anything

```
curl -o rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso 'https://access.cdn.redhat.com//content/origin/files/sha256/85/85a...46c/rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso?_auth_=141...7bf'
```

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Chapter 2. Downloading Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/chap-download-red-hat-enterprise-linux)
describes the process in detail.

In short, use the command

```
curl -o rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso from-location
```

The location is copied from the
[Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/home),
DOWNLOADS section, when you get to the actual link to your download.

Example from the article:

```
curl -o rhel-server-7.0-x86_64-dvd.iso 'https://access.cdn.redhat.com//content/origin/files/sha256/85/85a...46c/rhel-server-7.0-x86_64-dvd.iso?_auth_=141...7bf'
```

Comment: @KingDavid - Harry has provided you an example of the proper curl command.

Comment: You will find the version you prefer, server or workstation, from the [home page](https://getfedora.org/).

Comment: It worked but I had to go to the link you posted for "Customer Portal", finish creating an account, go to downloads page `https://access.redhat.com/downloads/`, and then copy the link from there, and the link is a very long url. Then you have to use `curl -o` method and to show the progress bar add `--progress-bar`.